# What types can we assign to K in HashMap<K,V>?

Tags: java, hashmap

What types can we assign to `K` in `HashMap<K,V>`? Is it only numeric types (`int`, `float`) or we can assign user defined objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use any type as long as it has sane [`equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) implementations.

Strictly speaking: you can use *any* reference type, but it won't work as expected if the type doesn't have sane implementations of those methods.

Note that you **can not** use the primitive types (`int`, `float`, ...) but can use their wrapper types instead (`Integer`, `Float`, ...). This is because generics can only handle reference types.

Answer (score 6):

You can user defined objects, but it is a good idea to define the `hashCode` and `equals` methods explictly in those classes.

You cannot use `int` or `float` because they are primitive types that are not derived from the `Object` superclass (which provides a default implementation of  `hashCode()` and `equals()`). If you do need to use ints or floats you need to use their object wrapper classes `Integer` and `Float`

Answer (score 2):

You can assign any class to `K`, including primitive types in their object forms (`Integer`, `Character`...).

Answer (score 1):

The only types you cannot use are primitives (and `void`), you can instead use wrapper class. i.e. the key and values have to be an object (or null).

If you want to use primitives, I suggest considering trove4j which is designed to handle primitives in collections efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Any object can be used as Key.

1. if you use user defined class object as key, be very care on
   override method  hashCode, equals.
2. take care to use mutable object as key. The behavior of a map is not
   specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that
   affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.